# OpenMP 3.0 for Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, openmp

Currently I am developing a cross-plattform framework where I want to use actuall features of openmp.
I would like to make use of the "new features" of openmp 3.0 (or later).
(Such like unsigned parallel for loops or tasks etc.,
I haven't developed on a windows plattform for quite a while and
as I have seen for now even Visual Studio 2015 does only support openmp 2.0 (At least when using msvc, see e.g. [All OpenMP Tasks running on the same thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23656592/all-openmp-tasks-running-on-the-same-thread) or  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2014/11/12/visual-studio-2015-preview-is-now-available/) So my questions are:

1. Is there any sane reason to not support openmp3.0 in Visual Studio?
   Is there any way to get it work under Visual Studio?
2. I am aware, that I could use the Intel C++ compiler, but unfortunately i do not have access to one. So is there a free alternative to the Intel compiler with openmp3.0 support?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/12/04/clang-with-microsoft-codegen-in-vs-2015-update-1/) you can find a description how to include clang 3.7 into MSVC 2015 update 1. I've no idea whether Open MP runs with it, but the chances are no that bad imo.

Comment: Oh cool thanks i'll give it a try

Comment: @davidhigh Huh?! Right on the page there is a statement `No OpenMP support. You will get a diagnostic that says “OpenMP is not supported”`

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux: ok. I haven't seen that, probably because of my "C++1z in MSVC" euphoria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you might try GCC ports for Windows, native (mingw64) and on top of cygwin.

Try to install [msys2](https://msys2.github.io/) and you'll get ming64 as well as cygwin compilers with OpenMP support

Answer (score 0):

You can try `cygwin`.

cygwin is gcc compiler by GNU for windows.